# JavaScript / JSP - Why won't the "CheckboxStateChange" eventListener work?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm creating a web project using JSP that creates a form based on values taken from a servlet. I'm trying to add an eventListener to some checkboxes that, at it's most basic, brings up an alertbox when checked or unchecked.

JSP:

```
<c:if test="${type == 'impactedSite'}">
                            <div id="${type}">
                                <div id="products">
                                    <h4>Product:</h4>
                                    <input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="product" value="Anaesthetic"> Anaesthetic<br />
                                    <input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="product" value="Analgesic"> Analgesic<br />
                                    <input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="product" value="Antacid"> Antacid<br />
                                </div>
                                <div id="processes">
                                    <h4>Process:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="equipment">
                                    <h4>Equipment:</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div><br /><br />
                        </c:if>
```

JavaScript:

```
if(document.getElementById("impactedSite")){

        var anaesthetic = ["a", "b", "c"];
        var analgesic = ["d", "e"];
        var antacid = ["f", "g"];

        var processesElement = document.getElementById("processes");

        var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBoxes");

        for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){

            alert("Checkbox" + i);

            checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("CheckboxStateChange", function(event){

                var checkbox = event.target;
                if (checkbox.checked) {
                    alert ("The check box is checked.");
                }
                else {
                    alert ("The check box is not checked.");
                }

            }, false);

        }

    }
```

My `<script>` tags are declared last in the `<body>`. The alert in the loop (`alert("Checkbox" + i);`) works fine, it's just checking and unchecking the boxes doesn't doesn't bring up the alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just `change` event:

```
checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("change", function(event){
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing I immediately see is that the event object reference is missing in the callback to the eventlistener. Have a look at below modified snippet:

```
checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("CheckboxStateChange", function(event){

            var checkbox = event.target;
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                alert ("The check box is checked.");
            }
            else {
                alert ("The check box is not checked.");
            }

        }, false);
```

Comment: CheckboxStateChange works only with Firefox. I assume you are using a different browser. More info at http://help.dottoro.com/ljihlcqe.php

Answer (score 0):

You probably found that event somewhere like here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/CheckboxStateChange . Note that this is just the **XUL Specification** (XML UserInterface Language) and not something included in HTML5 like for example the `change` Event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change . By using the change event as mentioned in the other answers, you'll get something that works on all browsers.

References to the XUL in MDN can sometimes be a bit confusing, for example when you find the reference to checkbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/checkbox and you think `<checkbox>` is a valid HTML Element, but it actually isn't.